# How to view the function source code in the new mongo shell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

It's possible view the function source code in legacy mongo shell - `mongo`.

```js
> db.users.find
function(query, fields, limit, skip, batchSize, options) {
    var cursor = new DBQuery(this._mongo,
                             this._db,
                             this,
                             this._fullName,
                             this._massageObject(query),
                             fields,
                             limit,
                             skip,
                             batchSize,
                             options || this.getQueryOptions());

    {
        const session = this.getDB().getSession();

        const readPreference = session._getSessionAwareClient().getReadPreference(session);
        if (readPreference !== null) {
            cursor.readPref(readPreference.mode, readPreference.tags);
        }

        const readConcern = session._getSessionAwareClient().getReadConcern(session);
        if (readConcern !== null) {
            cursor.readConcern(readConcern.level);
        }
    }

    return cursor;
}
```

However, in the new mongo shell - `mongosh`, it's not the same situation(only signature).

```js
test> db.users.find
[Function: find] AsyncFunction {
  returnsPromise: true,
  apiVersions: [ 1, Infinity ],
  returnType: 'Cursor',
  serverVersions: [ '0.0.0', '999.999.999' ],
  topologies: [ 'ReplSet', 'Sharded', 'LoadBalanced', 'Standalone' ],
  deprecated: false,
  platforms: [ 'Compass', 'Browser', 'CLI' ],
  isDirectShellCommand: false,
  acceptsRawInput: false,
  shellCommandCompleter: undefined,
  help: [Function (anonymous)] Help
}
```

Or print it with `toString()`

```bash
test> db.users.find.toString()
function wrapper(...args) {
  const origResult = orig.call(this, ...args);
  return (0, helpers_1.addHiddenDataProperty)(origResult, Symbol.for('@@mongosh.syntheticPromise'), true);
}
```

Also get a few GUI Clients which integrated with `mongosh` tested. the output vary.

1. Studio 3T(same as the shell)

```bash
function wrapper(...args) {
  const origResult = orig.call(this, ...args);
  return (0, helpers_1.addHiddenDataProperty)(origResult, Symbol.for('@@mongosh.syntheticPromise'), true);
}
```

2. MongoDB Compass(slightly different, but the same functionality)

```bash
'function t(...t){
  const r=e.call(this,...t);
  return(0,u.addHiddenDataProperty)(r,Symbol.for("@@mongosh.syntheticPromise"),!0)}'
```

3. NoSQLBooster for MongoDB(well, this surprised me the most)

```bash
function () {
  if ('undefined' !== typeof _transformQuery) {
    var args = _transformQuery && Object.values(arguments).map(function (it) {
      if (utils.isArray(it)) {
        it = it.map(function (x) {
          return _transformQuery(x)
        });

        return it;
      } else {
        return _transformQuery(it);
      }
    });

    return old.apply(this, args);
  } else
    return old.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Try `db.users.find.toString()`

Comment: Have a look at [MongoDB NodeJS Driver API documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.11/classes/Collection.html#find). There you find a link to the source code: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/v4.11.0/src/collection.ts#L761

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for your comments, I updated the decription. as you can see: `db.users.find.toString()` isn't work as expected.

Comment: Well, the new shell is implemeted with typescipt, the type system is far beyond my understanding. thank you anyway.